# java.lang.NullPointerException while creating DiskFileItem

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to write a unit test for handling a file upload controller using Spring 3. Now if I send the image over to my service method through the controller everything works fine. But when doing a straight unit tests I am getting a null pointer exception.

It appears that the property "dfos" inside the `DiskFilteItem` is null when I instantiate it manually but it is populated when retrieving a `MultipartFile` from the controller.

```
    File file = new File("//Users//test//Downloads//testimage.jpg");
    log.info("found file: " +file.exists());
    log.info("file size: " +file.length());
    String fieldName = "field";
    String contentType = "image/jpeg";
    boolean isFormField = false;
    String fileName = "testimage.jpg";
    int sizeThreshold = 10240;

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    // throws null pointer
    FileItem fi = factory.createItem(fieldName,contentType,isFormField,fileName);

    // so does this one
    DiskFileItem item = new DiskFileItem(fieldName, contentType, isFormField, fileName, sizeThreshold, file);
    MultipartFile f = new CommonsMultipartFile(item);
```

I feel like I am missing something silly in my setup. My pom file contains the following dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This code throws the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getSize(DiskFileItem.java:316)
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.(CommonsMultipartFile.java:60)
 at ImgurClientTest.testUploadImage(ImgurClientTest.java:58)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The issue is that `DiskFileItem.getSize()` is temporally coupled with `DiskFileItem.getOutputStream()` in that an internal field is initialized in `getOutputStream` and used in `getSize`.

The solution is to do

```
final File TEST_FILE = new File("src/test/resources/test.jpg");
final DiskFileItem diskFileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/jpeg", true, TEST_FILE.getName(), 100000000, TEST_FILE.getParentFile());
diskFileItem.getOutputStream();
```

before passing `diskFileItem` to the constructor of `CommonsMultipartFile`.

Comment: thanks diskFileItem.getOutputStream();  save our day ...great

Comment: Thank you! The must have was **diskFileItem.getOutputStream()**

Answer (score 0):

What does this part of this log say?

```
log.info("found file: " +file.exists());
log.info("file size: " +file.length());
```

But I think the problem might be because of this:

```
File file = new File("//Users//test//Downloads//");
```

It looks like it's pointing to a directory instead of a file, so maybe that is why you are getting a `NullPointerException` when you want to get the size of `DiskFileItem`

Comment: You are right that was a typo in the description, I have modified the original sample to point at a file. 

The log file entries show the following

2010-11-08 11:57:11,907[main           ] INFO                 ClientTest - found file: true
2010-11-08 11:57:11,908[main           ] INFO                 ClientTest - file size: 291812

Comment: If it solve your problem, please upvote and mark this as answer. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

And if none of the solutions above work for you as it happened for me :) simply ditch the **DiskFileItem** and use the solution bellow:

```
  final File fileToUpload = new File("src/test/resources/files/test.txt");
  final MultiValueMap<String, Object> request = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
  request.add("file", new FileSystemResource(fileToUpload.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not entirely related to the question. I ran into the same exception when deploying some file-upload code to GAE. I modified systempuntoout's code from here [using apache fileupload on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742684/using-apache-fileupload-on-gae) (which uses the streams part of apache commons) which then worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
new DiskFileItem(fieldName, contentType, isFormField, fileName, sizeThreshold, file);
```

results in a `null` value. Look into the [docs](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem.html) to see what's wrong or maybe you pass some `null` as parameters

Comment: No all values are populated with something, it appears to be how I am creating the DiskFileItem from scratch vs how Spring creates it when sending it from a controller. Stepping through the DiskFileItem code it appears to be missing an instantiation somewhere when doing it manually for the dfos parameter.