# using apache fileupload on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I use [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) in a java server-side app that has a html form with fields :

1. A destination fied that will be filled with email address of the destination mailbox
2. A message text with a message of the sender
3. A < input type=file ... field for uploading a photo. I can receive uploaded file (as a stream) but how

This app I want to upload on GAE . 
I can receive uploaded file (as a stream , using `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream`).

I want to receive too input textfields (i.e. 1) and 2)) - completed by the user of app)

I want to access these using `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem`  but I receive `java.rmi.server.UID is a restricted class`

Comment: Writting file on GAE is not allowed.

Comment: @gigadot Who said anything about writing files?

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [FileItemIterator](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemIterator.html) of the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import java.io.InputStream;
..
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
      res.setContentType("text/plain");

      FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
        String name = item.getFieldName();
        InputStream stream = item.openStream();

        if (item.isFormField()) {
          //regular form field
          resp.getWriter().println(("Form:" + name + " : " + Streams.asString(stream));
        } else {
          //fileform field 
          resp.getWriter().println(("File:" +name + " : " + item.getName());
        }

      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using a FileItemIterator... List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request); Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator(); ... but this was throwing a NullPointer at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileSystem.getTempFil‌​e because there is no file system... So your code that uses FileItemStream instead works fine on GAE... Thanks lots for posting

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Google App Engine and FileUpload](http://shogi-software.blogspot.com/2009/04/google-app-engine-and-file-upload.html)

You can't write directly to the filesystem in GAE, but take a look at [GAEVFS](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/), which uses the datastore and memcache to emulate a filesystem.

Comment: I do not want to make use of persistence on Google cloud , I want to use Streaming futures from FileUpload. I have already sent pictures but having 1) and 2) hard-coded in the servlet . But I do not how to get these 2 field dynamically ie typed by user of app.

Comment: Oops ment to comment on the answer above