# Can I get the HttpServletRequest request body without headers?

Tags: java, servlets, post, http-post

When a file is submitted to my server using a multipart/form-data POST, is it possible to retrieve only the content of the file from the HttpServletRequest object? The `request.getInputStream()` shows some headers included at the beginning and then `------WebKitFormBoundary...` at the end.

Can I get just the file data without having to parse the input stream and extract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could annotate your servlet with [@MultipartConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html), then you can use [HttpServletRequest#getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) to get the individual parts.

This is available starting from Servlet 3.0. If for some reason you're stuck on an older version of Java Servlets, you may choose to use [Apache Commons File Upload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html).

Comment: Thanks, sounds perfect, but em... eclipse is telling me that `HttpServletRequest` does not have a function called `getParts()` - I guess I need to be using a different version of Java. BTW, I'm using the Google App Engine.

Comment: I got everything working with additional help from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742684/using-apache-fileupload-on-gae