# Spring 4 multipart "NullPointerException" issue

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-4, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to upload file using multipart.

Using Spring 4.2.5 and Google app engine 1.9.34

jsp code:

```
<form method="post" action="/fileUpload.htm" id="uploadForm"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="uploadObj" type="file" class="filestyle"  data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-badge="false" data-input="false" data-buttonBefore="true"  data-buttonText="Choose File" multiple name="files" accept=".doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx,.pdf,.ppt,.pptx">
</form>
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fileUpload.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String fileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,HttpSession session,@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{

      if(!file.isEmpty()){
              ****
       }
}
```

mulitpart bean config:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    </bean>
```

Error log:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:312)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getTempFile(DiskFileItem.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getOutputStream(DiskFileItem.java:528)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
        at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:142)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:928)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at com.security.GaeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GaeAuthenticationFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What is the thing I am doing wrong?

Because if I use the below code everything works fine :

```
final ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload=new ServletFileUpload();
 FileItemIterator fileItemIterator=servletFileUpload.getItemIterator(httpServletRequest);
 while(fileItemIterator.hasNext()){
    ****
}
```

Comment: 1. you cannot use filesystem on App Engine. 2. it's better to use blobstore for file upload https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And finally I resolve the issue by setting System's property `java.io.tmpdir`.

In appengine-web.xml, adding:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/"/>
  ...
</system-properties>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception when using a FileItemsIterator...              List fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
                Iterator fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();... You might want to look at systempuntoout's solution [using apache fileupload on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742684/using-apache-fileupload-on-gae) which uses the streaming instead which I've tried it and it works.