# Can we create FileItem object from file name and location?

Tags: java, upload, fileitem

Can we create `FileItem` object from given file name and file location using Java?
If we use commons-fileupload jar we can upload file using jsp/html and in servlet on parsing request we will get `List<FileItem>`. But I want to do file upload using plain java where I want to create `FileItem` object manually (I don't want to use `byte[]` array to store the file). So is there any way to create `FileItem` object manually?

Comment: This guys answer was complete. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120635/java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-creating-diskfileitem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Use the [DiskFileItemFactory](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html) like this:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
FileItem fi = factory.createItem("formFieldName", "application/zip", false,
    "/var/temp/somefile.zip");
```

Obviously use content type and other parameters appropriate to your case.

Comment: DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
    FileItem fi = factory.createItem("formFieldName", "application/zip", false,pathToLoad);  
    File fileLoc=new File(pathToLoad);   
  factory.setRepository(fileLoc);  
  try {  
   File file=new File file=new File(pathToLoad+File.separator+fileName);  
   fi.write(file);

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.isInMemory(DiskFileItem.java:275)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:391)

Comment: I am getting this problem when i am creating FileItem manually